# How sent data beetween controllers

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I wonder how I can send data from one RequestMethod.POST to another, in the rest service.

I would like to send data from Orgin and Departure do / connect, where the backend takes place and the result is displayed,

I thought about doing it using a database, but I think it's incorrect.

I get data from the user using thymeleaf.

Please help

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Orgin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView orgin() {
     return new ModelAndView("Orgin.html", "FlightDTO", new FlightDTO());
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/Orginconnect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String orginconnect(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightDTO, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
     return "Departure.html";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/Departure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView departure() {
     return new ModelAndView("Departure.html", "FlightDTO", new FlightDTO());
 }



 @RequestMapping(value = "/DepartureConnect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String departureconnect(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightDTO, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
     System.out.println(flightDTO.getOrigin());
     return "Test.html";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/Search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView showForm() {
     return new ModelAndView("Test.html", "FlightDTO", new FlightDTO());
 }


 @RequestMapping(value = "/connect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightDTO, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

     String Request = buildurl.url(flightDTO);
     try {
         buildurl.url(flightDTO);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Invalid data can not build an URL" + e);
     }

     try {
         connectServiceIml.connect(buildurl.url(flightDTO));
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Problem with connection" + e);
     }

     String output =  connectServiceIml.connect(Request) ;

     try {                                               

         model.addAttribute("AirlineFirst", searchResult.getAirlineFirst(output));
         model.addAttribute("AirlineSecond", searchResult.getAirlineSecond(output));
         model.addAttribute("AirlineThird",  ////.... some code

         return "Results.html";
 }
```

Comment: Are both controllers in the same JVM?  If so why don't you just call the method directly?  No need to POST

Comment: You can call the method directly or you can use rest template

Comment: @SudipBolakhe What do You mean ? Could You give me some example please ? How can I do it properly ?

Comment: Like in the method `connect` call `submit` passing the necessary paramaters

Comment: Please write me more I try to deal with it but I have no idea.

Write me please a piece of code.